# What is the correct way to append a link button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, url, append

This is the button I want to append using jquery

```
<a href="{{url('admin/listing/'.$listing->id.'/item/'.$item->id.'/cat_create')}}" class="btn btn-warning">Create</a>
```

ini jquery code

```
var a = '<a href="{{url('admin/listing/'+data.listing_id+'/item/'+data.id+'/cat_create')}}" class="btn btn-warning">Create</a>'
```

This line gives me this error
Use of undefined constant data - assumed 'data'

I wanted to append this button when I create new entry

```
$('#items-list').append(a);
```

Any ideas which parts of the line cause the error?

Comment: Your are not escaping some `'`

Comment: That looks like a PHP error, not Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can update it directly using the attr method and passing in the attribute you want to modify as well as the value you want to set the attribute to:

```
var a = '{{url('admin/listing/'+data.listing_id+'/item/'+data.id+'/cat_create')}}";
$('#items-list').attr( "href", a );
```